# Woocommerce and AJAX add to cart broken

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, response

I have got problem with Woocommerce.
When I click multiple times "add_to_cart_button" on archive-page.php AJAX stops working and redirects to product page.

First I checked the server response and its just fine. 200 OK :)

Then i looked into scripts. I found add-to-cart.js:

```
if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
   window.location = response.product_url;
   return;
}
```

Great, I added simple alert:

```
if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
   alert(response.error);
   window.location = response.product_url;
   return;
}
```

Ok, "response.error" is equal to *true* when script is moving into this if... But why this if statement is being true? How can I read error status? $.fail doesn't work.

What is going on? Please help :/

Comment: The redirect to the product page is due to an error adding the product to the cart. If you have inventory, order maximums, product in cart maximums and any other limitations set this will happen. It's built in. Please look into your product setup.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Sometimes is even worse if you think about problem too much :)

Comment: Glad it's solved. I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect to the product page is due to an error adding the product to the cart. If you have inventory, order maximums, product in cart maximums and any other limitations set this will happen. It's built in. Please look into your product setup.

Answer (score 0):

I can add couple of things related to problems with WooCommerce add to cart ajax buttons:

- In WooCommerce tab (from WP dashboard) => Settings => Products tab you see two checkboxes, one for enable/disable async in buttons and another for redirect to cart page directly on adding to cart a product.
- Also I noticed that if product posts visibility setting is set as private will trigger error in ajax request response so will redirect to product page (if available). So watch out of this too.